# Running a 32bit Extended Stored Procedure on a 64bit Sqlserver 2008 R2

Tags: c++, sql-server, stored-procedures, 32bit-64bit

How can I run a 32bit Extended Stored Procedure on a 64bit Sqlserver 2008 R2.

I do not have access to the source of this Extended Stored Procedure since this is legacy code from a third party application.

I am currently getting the following error:

> Could not load the DLL D:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10.X\MSSQL\Binn\fledqproc.dll,
>   or one of the DLLs it references.
>   Reason: 193(%1 is not a valid Win32
>   application.).

The database is currently not running in any compatibility modes.

This extended stored procedure runs on all our SQL Server 2000 instances.

Comment: I assume it doesn't run now? aka have you tried?

Comment: no it's not currently running

Comment: Sounds like you might need to contact the Third Party and ask for an upgrade.

Comment: @Philip Kelley that's not really an option...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only fix I found for this is to run your code through a linked server in a 32-bit instance of SQL Server Express next to your 64-bit instance (32-bit instances can be installed on a 64-bit Windows server). Any version other than Express will do, but SQL Server Express adds no extra cost.

Not the most elegant solution, but no problem so far.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you decompile and recompile?